# Local multi-image slideshow

Tags: ios, swift

I have around 15 pictures that I want to set up as a slide show. I don't want the slides show to be full screen, I only want the slide show to take up the bottom half of the screen. I want the image to change very 2 seconds without the user touching anything. I have liked everywhere for this but I can't seem to find it.

If this is to hard then I would like to have a video play.But also only on the bottom half of the screen.

Comment: Can you try with having UIImageView changing images every 2 secs. One way is to create a timer for 2sec and on its expiry change the image in UIImageView.

Comment: May be this is what you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215535/playing-prepared-animation-in-ios/40217044#40217044

Comment: If you want your imgeView appears like slideShow as you mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325884/how-to-change-opacity-of-animated-gif-images-in-ios/40325927#40325927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A code fragment like this would work,

```
  for yourImage in ImageArray
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.image2P.isHidden = true
        self.image2P.image = yourImage
        UIView.transition(with: self.image2P, duration: 2.0, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
            self.image2P.isHidden = false
            }, completion: { _ in
          // next image will load
        })
    }
  }
```

What is it, a simple animation. You load an image from an Array of images into image2P imageView and it slowly but surely shows said image. On completion you could load another image and loop around the process again.

Of course on the completion you could fade out the image before loading a new one, basically a second UIView within the first.